# Logstash date invalid format

Tags: parsing, elasticsearch, logstash, grok

Trying to parse logs from a rsylog server and insert them to elasticsearch.
My incoming logline is

```
Feb 13 01:17:11 xxxx xxx-xxxx_error 2016/02/13 01:17:02 [error] 13689#0: *1956118 open() "xxxxxx" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: xxxxx.xx, request: "xxxxxxx HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx.xx"
```

I am extracting fields with the following logstash filters:

```
grok {
match => {
    "message" => [
            "(?<logstamp>\h{3} \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) %{WORD:hostname} (?<source>[^\s]+) (?<timestamp>\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) %{GREEDYDATA:error_message}" 
 ]
 }

date {
locale => "en"
match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
}

mutate {
remove_field => [ "@version", "_score", "message", "host", "_type", "logstamp" ]
}
```

Based on http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/, my syntax is sane.
I have two dates in the log line because the first one is when rsyslog received the line, and the second one is from nginx. What I want is to pass the second one to "timestamp".

The error I get in logstash is:

```
@metadata_accessors=#<LogStash::Util::Accessors:0x1d630482 @store={"path"=>"..."}, @lut={"[path]"=>[{"path"=>"..."}, 
"path"]}>, @cancelled=false>], :response=>{"create"=>{"_index"=>"...", "_type"=>"...", "_id"=>"...", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", 
"reason"=>"failed to parse [timestamp]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception",
"reason"=>"Invalid format: \"2016/02/16 12:25:16\" is malformed at \"/02/16 12:25:16\""}}}}, :level=>:warn}
```

(I clipped the output to make it shorter)

**EDIT: WORKING CONFIG**
I ended up converting the timestamp from Nginx log to a more standard one (as seen in the `ruby` part), and using that one in the `date` match as *@timestamp*.

```
  grok {
match => {
    "message" => [
            "(?<logstamp>\h{3} \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) %{WORD:hostname} (?<source>[^\s]+) (?<ngxstamp>[^\s]+ [^\s]+) %{GREEDYDATA:error_message}"
     ]
    }
}

ruby {
code => "event['ngxstamp'] = event.timestamp.time.localtime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')"
}

date {
match => [ "ngxstamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
locale => "en"
}

mutate {
remove_field => [ "@version", "_score", "message", "host", "_type", "logstamp" ]
}
```

Comment: It seems your date pattern is wrong: `yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss` should read `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss`, i.e. "month of year" should be `MM` not `mm`. Can you try that?

Comment: argh, sorry that was a wrong paste. a friend told me to intentionally put mm instead of MM, even though I told him mm stands for minutes. The error still holds for MM.

Comment: Ok, though the error is not at the logstash level, but more at the ES level, it seems. Can you show the mapping your have using `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index/_mapping/your_type`? It looks like the type of your timestamp field is a number somehow and not a `date` type...

Comment: ``"properties":{"@timestamp":{"type":"date","format":"strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"}`` - does the following suffice or should I paste the entire line?

Comment: The problem is with `strict_date_optional_time` whose format uses dashes and not slashes, i.e. `yyyy-MM-dd` and not `yyyy/MM/dd`. Then simply change your date pattern to: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` and it should work, though there might still be an issue with the missing `T`between the date and the time.

Comment: So I would need to change the log format from the source? Nginx doesn't allow to change format for error_log, and I have too many hosts to do this anyway. Maybe there is some filter in logstash to replace - with /. Or maybe I can disable strict_date_optional_time.

Comment: Have you tried to simply change the format in your `date` filter?

Comment: I've tried several date filters but none worked, so after a lot of tries I ended up doing a substitution (added in the main message). If you make an answer from your comments I can mark as accepted since you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the type of your `timestamp` field is `strict_date_optional_time`, the date pattern you should be using in your `date` filter should be

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

instead of

```
yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss
```

So:

- Use dashes instead of slashes in the date part
- use `MM` instead of `mm` for the months

There might still be an issue with the missing `T` between the date and time parts, since `strict_date_optional_time` mandates it, though.