# Logstash Squid date invalid format

Tags: datetime, logstash, squid, logfile

I am running ELK Stack on a server where I integrate Squid access.log file (combined format to also get the user-agent). It shows all logs properly in Kibana and my `logstash.stdout` file shows the entries correctly:

```
{
    "message" => "192.168.2.26 - - [06/Apr/2016:19:08:51 +0200] \"GET https://r2---sn-4gxx-25gs.googlevideo.com/videoplayback/id/o-ABKSIYjx-CBdsfnjHVg6926-k9evTCAai6SfBJ7AGoNA/itag/311/source/youtube/govp/slices%3D0-713,52432612-53212629/gosq/63/file/seg.ts?dnc=1&cpn=yH1AZUBmkDfs_UGh&sgovp=clen=186211243;dur=1154.849;itag=298;lmt=1459931359321727;gir=yes&ip=88.177.83.67&ratebypass=yes&mt=1459962265&playlist_type=DVR&ms=au&ipbits=0&pl=12&mv=m&mm=31&expire=1459984025&upn=egKraIHQnU8&pfa=1&keepalive=yes&fexp=9408541,9416137,9416891,9417405,9420452,9422542,9422596,9426927,9427015,9427902,9428269,9428333,9428398,9428567,9428769,9430014,9430058,9431045,9431614,9431850,9431976,9432026,9432429,9432631,9433548&sver=3&sparams=hls_chunk_host,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,mm,mn,ms,mv,pfa,pl,playlist_type,ratebypass,requiressl,sgovp,source,expire&signature=C55E2BDA79965F9062CB2306C7B082776587104A.3BACE1898A53453B99CF50CA230E127E8EC095E8&requiressl=yes&initcwndbps=682500&hls_chunk_host=r2---sn-4gxx-25gs.googlevideo.com&mn=sn-4gxx-25gs&key=yt6&dur=5.067 HTTP/1.1\" 200 350062 \"-\" \"AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.13B143 (iPad; U; CPU OS 9_1 like Mac OS X; fr_fr)\" TCP_MISS_ABORTED:ORIGINAL_DST",
   "@version" => "1",
 "@timestamp" => "2016-04-06T17:08:51.000Z",
       "path" => "/var/log/squid/access.log",
       "host" => "secbox.localdomain.local",
       "type" => "squid",
   "clientip" => "192.168.2.26",
      "ident" => "-",
       "auth" => "-",
  "timestamp" => "06/Apr/2016:19:08:51 +0200",
       "verb" => "GET",
    "request" => "https://r2---sn-4gxx-25gs.googlevideo.com/videoplayback/id/o-ABKSIYjx-CBdsfnjHVg6926-k9evTCAai6SfBJ7AGoNA/itag/311/source/youtube/govp/slices%3D0-713,52432612-53212629/gosq/63/file/seg.ts?dnc=1&cpn=yH1AZUBmkDfs_UGh&sgovp=clen=186211243;dur=1154.849;itag=298;lmt=1459931359321727;gir=yes&ip=88.177.83.67&ratebypass=yes&mt=1459962265&playlist_type=DVR&ms=au&ipbits=0&pl=12&mv=m&mm=31&expire=1459984025&upn=egKraIHQnU8&pfa=1&keepalive=yes&fexp=9408541,9416137,9416891,9417405,9420452,9422542,9422596,9426927,9427015,9427902,9428269,9428333,9428398,9428567,9428769,9430014,9430058,9431045,9431614,9431850,9431976,9432026,9432429,9432631,9433548&sver=3&sparams=hls_chunk_host,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,mm,mn,ms,mv,pfa,pl,playlist_type,ratebypass,requiressl,sgovp,source,expire&signature=C55E2BDA79965F9062CB2306C7B082776587104A.3BACE1898A53453B99CF50CA230E127E8EC095E8&requiressl=yes&initcwndbps=682500&hls_chunk_host=r2---sn-4gxx-25gs.googlevideo.com&mn=sn-4gxx-25gs&key=yt6&dur=5.067",
"httpversion" => "1.1",
   "response" => "200",
      "bytes" => "350062",
   "referrer" => "\"-\"",
      "agent" => "\"AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.13B143 (iPad; U; CPU OS 9_1 like Mac OS X; fr_fr)\"",
       "tags" => [
    [0] "squid"
]
```

}

However, the `logstash.log` file claims about date errors:

```
"error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse [timestamp]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"Invalid format: \"06/Apr/2016:18:51:04 +0200\" is malformed at \"/Apr/2016:18:51:04 +0200\""}}}}, :level=>:warn}
```

My `/etc/logstash/conf.d/squid.conf` file is defined as follows:

```
input {
  file {
    type => "squid"
    path => [ "/var/log/squid/access.log" ]
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "squid" {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
        add_tag => ["squid"]
    }
    date {
        match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => localhost }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I don't understand why I've this error message while logs seem to be parsed correctly by logstash.

Any idea? Thank you in advance for your inputs.

Comment: The parsing (grok) is working, but the date{} filter is failing.  It appears to think that your input and pattern don't match after the first slash, but the [debugger](https://staging-jodadebug.herokuapp.com/) likes it.

Answer (score 0):

though it has been a long time, think that the answer will help those who are facing this problem.
[Logstash date invalid format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35433291/logstash-date-invalid-format)

the url gives me the answer, to use mutate doing a substitution of the time format 
    mutate {
        gsub => ["timestamp","/","-"]
    }
    date {
        match => ["timestamp", "your format"]
    }